# Get Sequence of Rows (Linked-List) in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, linked-list

I have a table called `deliveries`. Some of these deliveries are a part of a sequence (having a parent or child or both), and some of these deliveries are one-offs.

```
id    parent_delivery_id    child_delivery_id
---------------------------------------------
1     NULL                  2
2     1                     3
3     2                     4
4     3                     NULL
5     NULL                  NULL
6     NULL                  NULL
7     NULL                  8
8     7                     NULL
```

Using the example above, I would like to write a bit of SQL to grab all of the deliveries in the sequence starting with delivery 1 and ending with delivery 4.

Expected selection:

```
id    parent_delivery_id    child_delivery_id
---------------------------------------------
1     NULL                  2
2     1                     3
3     2                     4
4     3                     NULL
```

Comment: Can you also post your expected result?

Comment: Yes, will do so now!

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution based on what I found here:

[Get Row's Sequence (Linked-List) in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643520/get-rows-sequence-linked-list-in-postgresql)

```
WITH RECURSIVE pathtobottom AS (
-- Get the path from element to bottom list following next element id that matches current link_id
  SELECT 1 i, -- add fake order column to reverse retrieved records
  * FROM deliveries WHERE deliveries.id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pathtobottom.i + 1 i, -- add fake order column to reverse retrieved records
  recursive.* FROM deliveries recursive
    INNER JOIN pathtobottom ON recursive.id = pathtobottom.parent_delivery_id
)
,  pathtotop AS (
-- Get the path from element to top list following previous element link_id that matches current id
  SELECT 1 i, -- add fake order column to reverse retrieved records
  * FROM deliveries WHERE deliveries.id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pathtotop.i + 1 i, -- add fake order column to reverse retrieved records
  recursive2.* FROM deliveries recursive2
    INNER JOIN pathtotop ON recursive2.parent_delivery_id = pathtotop.id
), pathtotoprev as (
-- Reverse path to top using fake 'i' column
  SELECT pathtotop.id FROM pathtotop order by i desc
), pathtobottomrev as (
-- Reverse path to bottom using fake 'i' column
  SELECT pathtobottom.id FROM pathtobottom order by i desc
)
-- Elements ordered from bottom to top
SELECT pathtobottomrev.id FROM pathtobottomrev where id != 1 -- remove element to avoid duplicate
UNION ALL
SELECT pathtotop.id FROM pathtotop;
```